# Activated plugin is stored as an object, rather than as a path

Tags: plugins, activation

This seems like a very unusual behavior: Usually, when activating a plugin, a path to the plugin's main file (or bootstrap) is stored in the database under `options.active_plugins`.
However, something in the following code is causing Wordpress to store the object itself, rather than a path to it, in the database.

Here is the plugin's bootstrap file (`bootstrap.php`):

```
/**
 * Plugin metadata
 */

require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'MyPlugin.php' );

$plugin = new MyPlugin();
$plugin->init();
```

After activation, the `active_plugins` option entry will look like this (retrieved using `get_option( 'active_plugins' )`:

```
Array {
    [0] => (object) MyPlugin
}
```

When the expected result would be:

```
Array {
    [0] => bootstrap.php
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just not add code outside of actions (callbacks attached to hooks and filters). Else your variables might conflict with global variables. The default/first action for a plugin bootstrap would be (depending on the type of plugin): `plugins_loaded` or `muplugins_loaded`.

Attach hooks from there on to `wp_loaded` if you want stuff to run on `init` (but make it multisite save - `init` has other drawbacks as well).

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that using a variable named `$plugin` as a part of the plugin's bootstrap process is causing Wordpress to store that variable's contents, rather than containing the file's path. To fix the issue, simply use a different variable name:

```
/**
 * Plugin metadata
 */

require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'MyPlugin.php' );

$plugin_starter = new MyPlugin();
$plugin_starter->init();
```